# Js & Jquery:Understanding a search code with JSON request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

i have a js search in my page that i don't get perfectly how does work because i don't know 100% js and jquery. As far as i think the code takes the input and search match with a link to a database that returns a JSON value depending on what name you put on the link (?name="the-input-name-here"), then, the code parse the json and determinates if the name of the input it's a valid surname and if it is the check if it has a running page, if it has redirects you to that page. If the input is a valid surname but doesn't have a running page it redirects you to "landing-page-yes.html". If the input isn't a valid surname it redirects you to "landing-page-no.html".

I need help to understand how the code does this in order to make a simplify version. How that call to another url database is parsed by the js ? How can i think something similar with a backend and ajax ? I need to understand 100% what this code does and i'm kinda lost.

THANKS !

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="srchid" width="100" onkeypress="submitonenter(document.getElementById('srchid').value, event, this)" />

<input onclick="nameCheck(document.getElementById('srchid').value);" value="CLICK HERE" type="button" style="background-color:#990033; color:#fff;border-style:outset;">

<div id="nameresults"></div>


<script >
<!--
 
Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {   
        if (this[i] === obj) {
            return true;   
        } 
    }   return false;
}
 
function cursor_wait() {
  document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
}
 
// Returns the cursor to the default pointer
function cursor_clear() {
  document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
}
 
function nameCheck(sName) {   
    sName = trim(sName);
    if(sName == ""){
        alert("Please enter a name!");
        return false;
    }
    cursor_wait();   
    routeToNameLookup(sName);
    cursor_clear();
}
 
function $(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
 
// Get JSONP
function getJSON(url){
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.setAttribute('src',url);
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
 
function testcb(data){
 //alert(data[0]);
}
 
function loaded(data) {
    var name = document.getElementById('srchid').value;
    var xmlhttp2;
   
    //Using innerHTML just once to avoid multi reflow
    $("nameresults").innerHTML = data[0];
    if($("nameresults").innerHTML == 1){
        if(data[1] == 1){
            //display name page with content
            var sNewName = name.replace (/'/g, ""); //remove any '
            sNewName = removeSpaces(sNewName);
            sNewName = convertNonAscii(sNewName);
            //redirect to name crest
            var sUrl = "http://www.heraldicjewelry.com/" + sNewName.toLowerCase() + "-crest-page.html";
            //getJSON("http://www.gohapp.com/updatenamesearch.php?id=" + data[2] + "&pageurl=" + sUrl + "&callback=testcb");
            //postwith(sUrl,{'pname':name});
            window.location=sUrl;
        } else {   
            //post to yes page
            //postwith("http://www.heraldicjewelry.com/landing-page-yes.html",{'pname':name});
                                                window.location="http://www.heraldicjewelry.com/landing-page-yes.html";
        }
    } else {
        //post to no page
        //postwith("http://www.heraldicjewelry.com/landing-page-no.html",{'pname':name});
                                window.location="http://www.heraldicjewelry.com/landing-page-no.html";
    }
    $("nameresults").innerHTML = "";
}
 
function routeToNameLookup(sSrchName) {
  var name = document.getElementById('srchid').value;
  if(sSrchName==""){
   alert("Please enter your family name.");
  } else {
      var rn=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000000000001)
      getJSON("http://www.gohapp.com/namesearch_new.php?name="+name+"&rec=1&callback=loaded&rn="+rn);
  }
}
 
function trim (sStr) {
    var str = sStr.replace(/^\s+/, '');
    for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (/\S/.test(str.charAt(i))) {
            str = str.substring(0, i + 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
 
function postwith (to,p) {
  var myForm = document.createElement("form");
  myForm.method="post" ;
  myForm.action = to ;
  for (var k in p) {
    var myInput = document.createElement("input") ;
    myInput.setAttribute("name", k) ;
    myInput.setAttribute("value", p[k]);
    myForm.appendChild(myInput) ;
  }
  document.body.appendChild(myForm) ;
  myForm.submit() ;
  document.body.removeChild(myForm) ;
}
 
function removeSpaces(string) {
 return string.split(' ').join('');
}
 
var PLAIN_ASCII =
    "AaEeIiOoUu" // grave
  + "AaEeIiOoUuYy" // acute
  + "AaEeIiOoUuYy" // circumflex
  + "AaOoNn" // tilde
  + "AaEeIiOoUuYy" // umlaut
  + "Aa" // ring
  + "Cc" // cedilla
  + "OoUu" // double acute
;
 
var UNICODE =
    "\u00C0\u00E0\u00C8\u00E8\u00CC\u00EC\u00D2\u00F2\u00D9\u00F9"
  + "\u00C1\u00E1\u00C9\u00E9\u00CD\u00ED\u00D3\u00F3\u00DA\u00FA\u00DD\u00FD"
  + "\u00C2\u00E2\u00CA\u00EA\u00CE\u00EE\u00D4\u00F4\u00DB\u00FB\u0176\u0177"
  + "\u00C3\u00E3\u00D5\u00F5\u00D1\u00F1"
  + "\u00C4\u00E4\u00CB\u00EB\u00CF\u00EF\u00D6\u00F6\u00DC\u00FC\u0178\u00FF"
  + "\u00C5\u00E5"
  + "\u00C7\u00E7"
  + "\u0150\u0151\u0170\u0171"
;
 
// remove accentued from a string and replace with ascii equivalent
function convertNonAscii(s) {
  if (s == null)
    return null;
  var sb = '';
  var n = s.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var c = s.charAt(i);
    var pos = UNICODE.indexOf(c);
    if (pos > -1) {
      sb += PLAIN_ASCII.charAt(pos);
    } else {
      sb += c;
    }
  }
  return sb;
}
 
function submitonenter(name, evt,thisObj) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : ((window.event) ? window.event : "")
        if (evt) {
            // process event here
            if ( evt.keyCode==13 || evt.which==13 ) {
              thisObj.blur();
              nameCheck(name);
              //alert("looking for " + name); 
            }
        }
    }
 
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Simplifying your code is outside of the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm pretty much grossed out by the getJSON() function and the redefinition of $() when the script uses jQuery.

Comment: You'r right, it wasn't correct to ask coding. I think it will be useful for me some help to understand the code so i can look out how to do it simplier. I'm sorry